# searching a dictionary within a dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can I check if the following collection of schemes has a certain string value?  I've read several similar examples but nothing is really helping me.
Many thanks,

**Example what I need**

```
    foreach(var item in data.Valuations)
    {
        if(item.Schemes.Contains("my string")) {
           // Do something 
        }
    }
```

**The code**

```
    public Valuation[] Valuations { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Schemes
    {
        get { return this.Values.Keys; }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> Values { get; internal set; }
```

**UPDATE**

I've managed to do it using the following line of code.

```
    var model = new DetailViewModel 
    {
        model.Data = ...
    }

    // New bit

    model.Data.SelectMany(x => x.Schemes).Where(x => x == "my string");
```

However when looking at the model.Data it hasn't applied the filter.  Am I missing something stupid?  The 'my string' is located in the Schemes

Comment: Is it really necessary to have a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: Nicolas Tyler: I didn't write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try linq with `SelectMany`:

```
if(Values.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Keys).Any(x => x == "my string"))
{
   //do your stuff here
}
```

This will create a collection of all the keys from the inner dictionaries, which you can search with subsequent queries, in this example - with `Any` which will return true if the string was found.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way of doing this is to use the `ContainsKey` method of the [dictionary class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx):

```
if (Values.ContainsKey("my string")) 
{

}
```

If you really want to operate on your `IEnumerable<String> Schemes` property, then you can simply ensure that `using System.Linq` is at the top of your code, and [.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) will work exactly as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
    if(schemes.Any(x=>x=="my string")) 
    {
       // Do something
    }
```

you can use `Any` from LINQ to check if there is any element matching predicate -> here checking if there is any string equals to "my string".

You can use `Contains` only if using `Lists` so other solution is:

```
public List<string> Schemes
{
    get { return this.Values.Keys.ToList(); }
}

public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> Values { get; internal set; }
```

and then

```
if(schemes.Contains("my string")) 
{
   // Do something
}
```

will be valid.

BUT I suggest using Linq instead of `Contains` on list.

Comment: Linq provides a [.Contains for an IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx), which IMHO is easier to read than `.Any(x => x == "my string")`

Comment: @Richard thanks for suggestion, but I prefer using `Any` because I can pass there any predicate